# Pass data from observable to observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typescript2.0, angular8

Just started learning rxjs.

I am confused how to throw the observable from the Data Service layer to UI component layer. Also if the DB layer throws an error can I catch it in the UI component layer if I rethrow at all the below layers?

This is my setup -

UI Component -

```
   OnInit() {
         dataService.GetData(req).Subscribe((d)=> {
            if(d) {
               comboBox.data = d;
            }
         }
       )
   }
```

Data Service - I am confused at this part

```
   GetData(req):Observable<Object[]> {

      backendService.querydb(request).Subscribe((res)=> {
          if(res) {
             result: Object[] = Convert result to the Object I can use.
             return of(result)
          }
        }         
      );     
   }
```

DB Service Layer -

```
   queryDB(request):Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(
            (rslt: any) => {
                return rslt;
            },
            (error) => {
                this.consoleLogError(error);
                throw error;
            }
        ));
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data Service should return on Observable - something like (pseudo code):

```
    GetData(req):Observable<Object[]> {

      return backendService.querydb(request).map(
        pipe((res)=> {
          if(res) {
             return "result converted to the Object I can use";
          } else {
             return "something else";
          }
        })         
      );     
   }
```